hx-on:? equivalent to hyperscript 'load' event
I have some existing code that uses the hyperscript library to do some validation styling on load:
<div _="on load add .error-text to #myOtherClass">Error messages here </div>

I'm trying to find the non-hyperscript equivalent that leverages hx-on with vanilla JavaScript. And in particular I want this code to run when HTMX inserts that element into the page.
What is an hx-on equivalent to the Hyperscript on load syntax?

That would be:
hx-on:load="console.log('hi')"

Have in mind that this event may not work for all elements as explained here.

Good point that it could work for something like body. Thanks for including that link. The primary usecase is when using elements that are inserted by HTMX. it doesn't work for those cases.
I would like a solution the just works without caveats.
